# type object 'MODEL' has no attribute 'USERNAME_FIELD'

Tags: django, django-models

[image]
https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/obpvsm/i_dont_get_this_error_cant_find_anything_on_the

SO this issue here is, a lot of the solutions just had a lot of code, and not a direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

answered by reddit user - DurzoB4  u/DurzoB4

"You need to add the USERNAME_FIELD to your model not your admin."

"Yeah: USERNAME_FIELD = name (you don't need the quotes)"

something like this will work!